Create Rule in Magento 2.4 If a combined $X amount of items in Y category, then get free ship
I have been searching for days but cannot find a way to do this. If you know of an extension to pull this off, I'm open to it.
We want to offer a coupon code.
If you have $100 or more of products in X Category(s), get free shipping.
The two challenges that I have are:

I can't find a way to make a rule that adds up row totals for
products in a specific category.

We use Flat Rate Shipping as our default shipping, and Fedex for
faster speeds if the customer wants. I have been unable to find a
reliable way of offering free shipping with this shipping
configuration.


Test 1
Under Rule Condition
If ALL these conditions are TRUE:
|  If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true
|  |  Category is one of 20, 21
|  |  Price in cart equals or greater than 100

Actions
If ALL these conditions are TRUE:
|  Category is one of 20, 21
|  Price in cart equals or greater than 100

Test 2
Under Rule Condition
If ALL these conditions are TRUE:
|  If an item is FOUND in the cart with ALL of these conditions true
|  |  Category is one of 20, 21
|  Price in cart equals or greater than 100

Actions
If ALL these conditions are TRUE:
|  Category is one of 20, 21


Thanks to 2 different stack exchange posts, I figured it out.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28334100/magento-shopping-cart-price-rules-how-can-i-set-a-rule-when-amount-50-in-one/28336670#28336670
How can I give discount on shipping costs?
So, logic ended up being
Under Rule Condition (Select Product Subselection and change Total Quantity to Total Amount)

If ALL these conditions are TRUE:
|  If total amount is equal or greater than 100 in the cart with ALL of these conditions true
|  |  Category contains 20, 21


Actions
Apply: Fixed amount discount
Discount Amount: 15 (our flat rate shipping price).
Apply to Shipping Amount:  YES


If ALL these conditions are TRUE:
|  SKU is NONE

Since we don't want to apply the discount to the items in the cart, just the shipping, then we make sure not to let it apply to any SKU's in the cart, just what's left, i.e. the shipping.
